# equivalent code of winforms in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, winforms

I worked in winfoms previously. There was KeyPress event. So I can get the KeyChar.

The below code worked in winforms

```
Dim allowedChars as String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "

If allowedChars.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) = -1
    If Not e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Back) Then
        e.Handled = True
        Beep()
    End If
End If
```

But in WPF I dont know how to implement the above code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752494/detect-if-any-key-is-pressed-in-c-sharp-not-a-b-but-any

Comment: I think those who dont know the answer to my question, are marking it negative.

Comment: @Vishal: I don't really think so. I think people do it for every post they find on SO already containing this issue (PS, I even didn't downvote).

Comment: I didn't down vote, but if you hover over the down vote button it says "question doesn't show research effort". I think their votes are valid

Comment: @Vishal: is this to validate input to a textbox?

Comment: @DanPuzey yes. This is to validate input to a textbox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF TextBox Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079552/wpf-textbox-validation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is C#, but you can easily convert it to VB.NET.

```
private void NumericTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    char c = (char)KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey(e.Key);

    if ("ABCDEF".IndexOf(c) < 0)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid character.");
    }
}
```

You may need to import `System.Windows.Input` to get `KeyInterop`. The code segment above goes into the `PreviewKeyDown` event of the TextBox.

All of the above and more can be seen [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/81863/Key-press-event-in-WPF)

Comment: Thanks for your good effort to answer my question. But I want some specific letters or symbols to my textbox like A-Z,a-z,:?.I mean I want a textbox to accept only `A-Z,a-z,:?.`

Comment: that's pretty easy to implement, isn't it? You already have the incoming character. You could use your `IndexOf` technique you have in your original code above. Let me update my code.

Comment: @Vishal: Updated my code. You can replace ABCDEF with all the characters that you want to allow in the textbox.

Comment: Now I want to add some special keys to the list. like backSpace, Home, End, PgUp, PgDown, Arrow Keys, Insert and all the shortcut keys of my application. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure. You can do `if(e.Key != Key.Back && e.Key != Key.Space)` etc. to achieve that.

Comment: sorry to say but now I got a problem with the above code. It does not accept any punctuation marks. like `,./';[]`

Comment: I found a way from another question. My answer is posted below.

Answer (score 1):

In C#

```
private bool ValidChar(string _char)
{
   string Lista = @" ! "" # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z ";
   return Lista.IndexOf(_char.ToUpper()) != -1;
}

private void textBoxDescripcion_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    if (!ValidChar(e.Text))
         e.Handled = true;
}
```

In vb

```
Private Function ValidChar(_char As String) As Boolean
    Dim Lista As String = " ! "" # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z "
    Return Lista.IndexOf(_char.ToUpper()) <> -1
End Function

Private Sub textBoxDescripcion_PreviewTextInput(sender As Object, e As TextCompositionEventArgs)
    If Not ValidChar(e.Text) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```