# Validation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding

I have 3 TextBoxes in my window.When i enter wrong charecters into the TextBoxes ,It should show error by using validations.I'm doing this in WPF, please help me with the code

This is my XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="DataGrid_DataBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="IDDATA" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn="DG1_AutoGeneratingColumn" Name="dgsample" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserSortColumns="False"  Margin="200,10,10,75">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Salary" Binding="{Binding Path=Salary}"  />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <Label  Content="ID :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="27"/>
    <Label  Content="Name :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="48"/>
    <Label  Content="Salary :" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Width="47"/>

    <TextBox Name="tb1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="60,10,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Id, ElementName=dgsample,ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />

    <TextBox Name="tb2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="60,60,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=dgsample,ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
    <TextBox Name="tb3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="60,110,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Salary, ElementName=dgsample,ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>

    <Button Content="Get" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,190,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Get_Click" />
    <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,230,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Add_Click" />
    <Button Content="Delete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,270,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Delete_Click" />
</Grid>
```

This is .cs Code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<User> Users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Users.Add(new User() { Id = 101, Name = "allen", Salary = 10 });
        Users.Add(new User() { Id = 102, Name = "scott", Salary = 20 });
        Users.Add(new User() { Id = 103, Name = "mickey", Salary = 30 });
        Users.Add(new User() { Id = 104, Name = "micheal", Salary = 40 });
        Users.Add(new User() { Id = 105, Name = "fletch", Salary = 50 });
        Users.Add(new User() { Id = 106, Name = "etcher", Salary = 60 });

        dgsample.ItemsSource = Users;

    }
    private void DG1_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Column.Header.ToString())
        {
            case "Id":

                e.Column.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                break;
            case "Name":
                e.Column.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                break;
            case "Salary":
                e.Column.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Get_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        int index;
        if (int.TryParse(this.tb1.Text, out index))
        {
            User currentUser = Users.FirstOrDefault(Select => Select.Id == int.Parse(tb1.Text));
            if (currentUser != null)
            {
                this.tb2.Text = currentUser.Name;
                this.tb3.Text = currentUser.Salary.ToString();
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("User with the provided ID does not Exist", "Error");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("ID entered is not valid number", "Error");





    }



    private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        if (!tb1.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            var adduser = Users.Where(User => User.Id == int.Parse(tb1.Text));

            if (!adduser.Any())
            {
                Users.Add(new User() { Id = int.Parse(tb1.Text), Name = tb2.Text, Salary = int.Parse(tb3.Text) });
            }

            else

                MessageBox.Show("Someone already has that ID.");

        }

    }

    private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index;
        if (int.TryParse(this.tb1.Text, out index))
        {
            User currentUser = Users.FirstOrDefault(Select => Select.Id == int.Parse(tb1.Text));
            if (currentUser != null)
            {
                Users.Remove(currentUser);
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("User with the provided ID does not Exist", "Error");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("ID entered is not valid number", "Error");

    }

}
```

Comment: So what's the problem with your code? What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer here:

[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079552/wpf-textbox-validation)

The most simple would be like this:

First implement `IDataErrorInfo` on your `User` class, so it would more or less look like this:

```
public class User : IDataErrorInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    private int salary;
    public int Salary {
        get
        {
            return salary;
        }
        set
        {
            salary = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Salary");
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;
            if (columnName == "Name")
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
                {
                    result = "Please enter a First name";
                }
            }
            if (columnName == "Salary")
            {
                if (Salary <= 0)
                {
                    result = "Please enter a valid salary";
                }
            }
            if (columnName == "Id")
            {
                if (Id < 0)
                {
                    result = "Please enter a valid id";
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public User()
    {

    }

    public User(int id, string name, int salary)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Salary = salary;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then create a property in your `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file:

```
private User currUser;
public User CurrUser { get; set; }
```

And just to see that it works in your constructor add:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    CurrUser = new User();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Add this to your `Window` in `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window
Name="myWindow"
...
```

Finally you can add your `TextBoxes` like this:

```
<TextBox Name="tb1" Height="23" Margin="51,191,0,0" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=CurrUser.Id,  ElementName=myWindow, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"/>
<TextBox Name="tb2" Height="23" Margin="51,219,0,0" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=CurrUser.Name,  ElementName=myWindow, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"/>
<TextBox Name="tb3" Height="23" Margin="50,163,0,0" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=CurrUser.Salary,  ElementName=myWindow, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}"/>
```

And now if the conditions in the class `User` will not be meet by the `TextBoxe.Text`, their borders will turn red, which tells there is validation problem.

[image: Validation screen]

**EDIT as requested from the question owner**

Also to use the validation with **TextBoxes** connected to the currently selected item in the **DataGrid** you can add the **SelectionChanged** event to the grid and implement it like:

```
private void dgsample_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = dgsample.SelectedIndex;

    CurrUser.Id = users[index].Id;
    CurrUser.Salary = users[index].Salary;
    CurrUser.Name = users[index].Name;
}
```

But to notify the **TextBox** about the property changes you have to make some additional changes into the **User** class ( updated the code at the beginning of the answer ).

My **Grid** definitione:

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid Name="Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="326,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.083,-1.154" Height="140" Width="181" FontStyle="Normal" SelectionChanged="Grid_SelectionChanged">
```

**Code-behind** - MainWindow constructor

```
public MainWindow()
{
    CurrUser = new User();
    users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
    users.Add(new User() { Id = 101, Name = "gin", Salary = 10 });
    users.Add(new User() { Id = 102, Name = "alen", Salary = 20 });
    users.Add(new User() { Id = 103, Name = "scott", Salary = 30 });
    users.Add(new User() { Id = 104, Name = "a", Salary = 30 });

    InitializeComponent();
    Grid.ItemsSource = users;
}
```

To be honest all you need can be found here:

[www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15239/Validation-in-Windows-Presentation-Foundation)

[codeblitz.wordpress.com](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/)

Comment: Exception based validation is the worst of features. Not even sure why Microsoft put it in. Never use exceptions to enforce business rules, especially user input. Is typing 'A' instead of '1' really a failure state?

Comment: @user2889489 yes I updated my answer, for this solution you will have to create 3 properties to store the values of currently `selected item`, plus you will have to add the `SelectionChanged` event to `DataGrid` to update the values of these properties.

Comment: @Gusdor that was the reason of downvote? You really wanted me to provide him with full Validation Rule? As stated thats the simple way of validating, I also provided him with the link for more information, so it's not true that the answer is not useful. Anyway I have changed the answer not to use exceptions.

Comment: @Tafari The answer is not useful to this viewer but the community (and the OP!) can prove me wrong). Sorry for any offense!

Comment: IDataErrorInfo will be deprecated sometime. Use INotifyDataErrorInfo instead

Comment: @Gusdor why not? He asked for validation, he never specified that he doesn't want to use exceptions, wants it to be optimal, short etc. Don't really get why the community here so easily downvotes answers, especially when they do not provide any on their own.

Comment: @Shoe I have heard that it's supported by WPF 4.5, so the solution using it would be useful only for that particular version, but I am not sure as I have never used it.

Comment: @Tafari If not u can edit my code replacing with ur answer and please check

Comment: @user2889489 have you also changed the implementation of the `User` class, as I told you?

Comment: @Then it has to be something wrong in your code as it works for me. But what's wrong there is an exception? An error? Or it just does nothing? Anyway I'm off for now so I'll answer your next comment in the evenening, see you.

Comment: @user2889489 sure but still you haven't said what is the problem with `SelectionChanged` I gave you, as for me it works properly, so I do not really know how to help you.

Comment: @user2889489 I have updated my answer (**SelectionChange** part) to match with your code, try to use it, as I think you had the wrong name for the **DataGrid** there.

Comment: For me it looks like the grid is built different in your application. I will provide you with my grid definitione both in XAML and code-behind.

Comment: @Tafari even for textbox validation the code u given is not working can u please check it again

Comment: @user2889489 previously you have said that it works, if you can craete a blank project and use the code for validation I provided you will see that it works.

Comment: @Tafari Defaulty when i execute it shows 0 in the textbox how can i remove it

Comment: @user2889489 well it shows it as it is binded to the property **ID** and **Salary** which at the beginning are **0** (caused by this `CurrUser = new User();` in your **constructor**), you wanted them to be int, so they can't be empty. I think it might be possible to hide it, but for now I am not really sure how to 'fix' it. What I can recommend you is to remove mentioned line from the constructor and add this instead: `CurrUser = new User(users[0].Id, users[0].Name, users[0].Salary);`, so it will show details of first user in the list **users**.